# What is $P(A\mid B, C)$ if $B$ and $C$ are independent?

Tags: probability

What is $P(A\mid B,C)$ if $B$ and $C$ are independent to each other?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with $B,C$?

Comment: P(A|B,C) = P(A|B)P(A|C) if B and C are conditionally independent.

Comment: BTW, this is a legit question. I don't know why its marked as off topic. It needs no extra context.

Answer (score 3):

$$
p(a |b, c) = \frac{p(a, b, c)}{p(b, c)} =  \frac{p(a, b, c)}{p(b) p(c)}.
$$
The first equality uses Bayes's theorem and the second the independence of $b$ and $c$. You can rewrite the numerator in a number of ways using Bayes's law again, if desired.

Comment: Keep going ... if b and c independent then p(a,b,c) = p(a,b)*p(a,c) which means that p(a,b,c) /(p(b)*p(c)) =p(a,b)*p(a,c)/(p(b)*p(c)) = p(a|b)*p(a|c).